# call setter from __init__ in Python

Tags: python-3.x, class, properties, setter

I have a class such as this:

```py
class Ticket:
    def __init__(self, ticket):
        self._subject = ticket.subject
        self._oem = self.oem()
    
    @property
    def oem(self):
        return self._oem

    @oem.setter
    def oem(self):
        #set oem value by extracting it from subject using regex
        self._oem = re.findall('<OEM: (.*?)>', self._subject)[0].strip()
```

However, on creating an object,

```
obj = Ticket(test_ticket)
```

I get an error,

```
AttributeError: 'Ticket' object has no attribute '_oem'
```

I've looked at similar questions, but they are not asking the same thing as I am.
I want to set the value for oem in the `__init__` method, by using the value from a previous variable, not by passing the value from outside.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: What do you expect `self._oem = self.oem()` to do? Also note that your setter is missing an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A property setter needs to accept a value, it would be invoked when assigning to the attribute e.g.

```
t = Ticket()
t.oem = value  # this would call call Ticket.oem(t, value)
```

If this property just uses the data from `self._subject` then don't write a setter at all. Instead, make the attribute a dynamically calculated and read-only property, like this:

```
class Ticket:
    def __init__(self, ticket):
        self._subject = ticket.subject
    
    @property
    def oem(self):
        return re.findall('<OEM: (.*?)>', self._subject)[0].strip()
```

Comment: Okay, understood. But, every time I need to access it, some processing will take place, is this correct? Suppose I know that I'll be using this value 5 times, and I would have 6 such values which will be calculated dynamically. Then, every time these values will be accessed, they will go through some logic I define. I imagine that would be less efficient (but maybe not noticeable)

Comment: Yes, and Python does about 5000 other things every time you access it too. For a simple regex find it won't matter a cent, so don't worry about it.

Comment: `@cached_property` - @wim I think this would be a good thing to do as well. 
For each object, the OEM (or other properties) will remain constant throughout the life of the object. Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cached_property